# Send email at specified time

Tags: email

I would like to send emails at a specified time.

I found this, but it is too complex for me to setup.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228105/sending-email-out-at-a-specific-time

Any alternatives especially a GUI method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simpliest way is to send emails at a specific time using the email client "Thunderbird" and the addon "Send later" https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/send-later-3/
Important: Thunderbird should be active at the requested time/date. If not the addon will send the Email the next time you start the client...

Another method (out of the Ubuntu-Universe) is using the Browser "Google Chrome" and the extension: "Right Inbox for Gmail" from the Chrome Web Store. With this method even if the computer is not running the mail will be sent at the specified time.